# Internal Blog Accessable by Remote employees

Tags: wordpress, web, blogs

I am currently working with a friend on starting a business.  Some of this work is being done remotely by each of us.  I know there are a lot of companies out there doing this and I am wondering how I can setup an internal blog thing similar to what Zapier talks about on a public web server.  I would like to make it so that the blog posts are things fed from Slack and other integrations as well.  Would doing it with a sub domain and a log in be really the best way to go with it?

Mostly just looking for thoughts and ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, it's super subjective to say "this is how it works" when it comes to communication & productivity.

I've been working remotely for the past two years and all I can say it's impossible for me to work without these tools:

- Slack with a paid plan ("When you're on Slack, you're at the office" rule + video calls)
- Trello / Airtable (task management & product design / KPI reporting)
- Zapier to set custom notifications (new invoice uploaded on Dropbox, new cards added in Trello)
- a great email manager (I like Spark)

Just try as many tools as you need, pick up your favorites and get rid off those you never use and everything will be fine. **Also, read this book from Zapier's CEO Wade Foster, it's super inspiring: https://zapier.com/learn/remote-work/**

I like the idea of feeding a private blog, I've done that once for a company on Medium and I was surprised how everyone read and reacted to the article.

You could set up a zap like this:

- Trigger: every time a message is posted in a given Slack channel
- Action: creates a new post in WordPress.

[image: Zapier example]

So if you really want to try it, looks like you can ;)

Comment: Awesome I think that is more or less what I am looking to do.  As a side note while I do not have a remote job (am looking for one) I do use Slack at my current job and love it.  The integration with all the other applications really increase my work flow all without being distracted by the verbal conversation of the office space.  I also read that book and it is inspiring to know that there are places out there like Zapier where one can work from home and actually be more productive than in traditional offices.  Thanks again @DFATPUNK I will have to try this out.

Comment: Remote work when done the right way can lead to a greater effficiency indeed. It’s not easy the first weeks but once you’re on the right paths, you’re done for good with office jobs. Reading essays from Wade Foster from Zapier and Joel Gascoigne from Buffer is always a good move. Keep us informed, always good to exchange about professional experiences. If my answer suits you, could you validate it please? Cheers ;)